Dictionary with a list of tuples as values. How can I replace a tuple in the list with a new tuple using a function
Using a function add_course, I want to replace a tuple in a list with a new tuple if one of the values in the new tuple is greater than the corresponding value of the tuple that is currently in the list.
here is my code:
def add_student(students, name):
    if name not in students:
        # students.update(name:[])
        students[name] = []

def print_student(students, name):
    if name not in students:
        print(f"{name}: no such person in the database")
    elif len(students[name]) < 1:
        print(f"{name}:")
        print(" no completed courses")
        # 
    elif len(students[name]) > 0:
        print(f"{name}:")
        print(f" {len(students[name])} completed courses:")
        for course in students[name]:
            # print(f"{len(students[name])}  completed courses:")
            print(f"  {course[0]} {course[1]}")
        av_grade = 0
        for course in students[name]:
            av_grade += course[1]
        print(f" average grade {av_grade / len(students[name])}")

def add_course(students,name,course: tuple):
    if course[1] == 0:
        return 0
    elif course[0] in students[name]:
        temp = course
        if temp[1] < course[1]:
            return 0
        else:
            course = temp
    students[name].append(course)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    students = {}
    add_student(students, "Peter")
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 3))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Advanced Course in Programming", 2))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Data Structures and Algorithms", 0))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 2))
    print_student(students, "Peter")


In the "main" code above you can see that "Peter" has taken the course "Introduction to Programming" twice, with his score listed as part of the tuple. If Peter's score is greater than the first time he took the course, I need to replace the lower scoring tuple with the higher. Conversely, if Peter's score is less than the first time he took the course I need to "not add" the completed course ("return 0" is my thought). I know my add_course function syntax is wrong but I'm hoping I'm on the right track?
output should be:
Peter:
 2 completed courses:
  Introduction to Programming 3
  Advanced Course in Programming 2
 average grade 2.5

my current output is:
Peter:
 3 completed courses:
  Introduction to Programming 3
  Introduction to Programming 2
  Advanced Course in Programming 2
 average grade 2.33

I have searched for hours for a solution but I'm not Python-savvy enough at this point to not ask for help.

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I think Barmar nailed the answer to this question. Only thing I would add is that, as you get more into Python, take a look at classes to store and manipulate data. Once you get past a level or two of nesting tuples, lists, and dictionaries, it can be really helpful to give yourself more specific, explicit abstractions.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site for specific questions, so "am I on the right track" is too broad. I don't see an easy way to pivot to a more specific question since there are multiple unrelated problems with your add_course function. I mean, if temp[1] < course[1] is good, but pretty much everything else there is wrong, including the definition of temp.

Please read How to ask and answer homework questions. Even if this isn't homework per se, some of the same tips still apply, like "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation".

You might try breaking down the problem from the top: Firstly, how do you loop over a list (students[name])? Try just printing the items to start, then once you have that, move on to the next step: comparing the course names. See also Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?

FWIW, if the list can't have duplicate courses, using a dict would make more sense

Loop over the list, looking for the course name. If you find it, replace that element with the new tuple and return. If you don't find it, append the new tuple.
def add_course(students,name,course: tuple):
    if name not in students:
        raise ValueError(f"{name}: no such person in the database")
    if course[1] == 0:
        return
    for i, (cname, cvalue) in enumerate(students[name]):
        if cname == course[0]: # course found, replace it if necessary
            if cvalue < course[1]:
                students[name][i] = course
            return

    # course not found, add it
    students[name].append(course)


I would highly recommend to use namedtuple instead of tuple here, because it will make your code much more readable. I would also suggest you to use dict for storing courses, as it will make such operations much easier and faster. In my example I convert your list in dict manually, just to show how easier it could be.
from collections import namedtuple

Course = namedtuple("Course", ["name", "score"])

def add_course(students: dict[str, list[Course]], name: str, new_course: Course) -> None:
    if name not in students:
        # Add a student or raise an error

    # Here I build a dict, but you can just store your courses as dict by default.
    courses: dict[str, Course] = {course.name: course for course in students[name]}

    if new_course.name not in courses or new_course.score > courses[new_course.name].score:
        courses[new_course.name] = new_course

    students[name] = list(courses.values())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    students = {}
    add_student(students, "Peter")
    add_course(students, "Peter", Course(name="Introduction to Programming", score=3))
    add_course(students, "Peter", Course(name="Advanced Course in Programming", score=2))
    add_course(students, "Peter", Course(name="Introduction to Programming",score=2))


Hope it will help!
